# cannot add object to list, add does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple radio station class. The RadioPlayer class will store a List of radio stations. Although for some reason I can not add radio stations to a List of radio stations. Can anyone tell me why? It says

> "stations.Add does not exist in the current context"

I am also using `System.Collections.Generic`.

```
namespace CATest
{
    public interface IStreamable
    {

    }
    public enum Genre
    {
        General,
        Music,
        News
    }

    public class RadioStation : IStreamable
    {
        public const double MinFreq = 87.5;
        public const double MaxFreq = 108;

        private double frequency;
        public string StationName { get; set; }
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        public double Frequency
        {
            get
            {
                return frequency;
            }
            set
            {
                //validate frequency
                if(value > MinFreq && value < MaxFreq)
                {
                    frequency = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Frequency must be between 87.5 and 108");
                }
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Station Name: {StationName} \nStation Genre: {Genre} \nStation Frequency: {Frequency}";
        }


    }

    public class RadioPlayer
    {
        private List<RadioStation> stations = new List<RadioStation>();
        stations.Add(new RadioStation() { Frequency = 100, StationName = "Radio2", Genre = Genre.Music });

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a method to add various items (during runtime) to the list or do you want to define a list with a fixed initial value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do this inside a method or constructor or somewhere. You cannot place this just within the class declaration.

```
public void AddStations(RadioStation station)
{
    stations.Add(station);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant add in the class level you must declare method and this method do the behaviour that you need meanwhile you can define the list in class level but any operation should happens inside method or contractor

```
public class RadioPlayer
    {
        List<RadioStation> stations = new List<RadioStation>();
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            stations.Add(new RadioStation() { Frequency = 100, StationName = "Radio2", Genre = Genre.Music });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to use [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.8) method at the class context. You can use `List` initializer to add an item(s) to list at creation time

```cs
private List<RadioStation> stations = new List<RadioStation>() 
{
    new RadioStation() { Frequency = 100, StationName = "Radio2", Genre = Genre.Music }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you do it inside the constructor.

Here's the implementation

```
public class RadioPlayer
{
    public RadioPlayer() 
    {
        stations = new List<RadioStation>();
        stations.Add(new RadioStation() { Frequency = 100, StationName = "Radio2", Genre = Genre.Music });
    }
    private List<RadioStation> stations; 
}
```